# javafx.application.applicationを拡張する必要がありますというエラーがでました

Tags: java

コマンドプロンプトでjavaファイルをjavacでコンパイルして実行しようとしたんですが、以下のエラーが出ました。

```
C:\Users\rqwqk\Desktop\pleiades\workspace\konpairuzikken\src>java wrqrqr
エラー: メイン・メソッドがクラスwrqrqrで見つかりません。次のようにメイン・メソッドを定義してください。

    public static void main(String[] args)

またはJavaFXアプリケーション・クラスは`javafx.application.Application`を拡張する必要があります
```

wrqrqr.javaの内容は以下の通りで、実行環境はWindows 7(x64)です。解決方法募集します。

```
public class wrqrqr {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static class helloworld{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO 自動生成されたメソッド・スタブ
            int x;
            x=5;
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 回答では触れませんでしたが、`helloworld`クラスは何か意図があって定義されているクラスでしょうか？

Comment: helloworldは無視してください。上記をコピペしてみたのですが、変わらなかったので、再度javacしてみたところ、javacができていないことがわかりまして、 javac wrqrqrで
C:\Users\rqwqk\Desktop\pleiades\workspace\konpairuzikken\src>javac wrqrqr
エラー: クラス名'wrqrqr'が受け入れられるのは、注釈処理が明示的にリクエストされた
場合のみです
エラー1個

と出ました。。これが原因でしょうか？

Comment: 回答にも記載しましたが`javac wrqrqr.java`と拡張子まで含めたコマンドでコンパイルしないとそのようなエラーが出るようです。再度試してみてください。

Comment: 次に出たエラーがC:\Users\rqwqk\Desktop\pleiades\workspace\konpairuzikken\src>javac wrqrqr.java
wrqrqr.java:1: エラー: この文字は、エンコーディングMS932にマップできません
?ｿpublic class wrqrqr {
^
エラー1個　　と出てきました。。

Comment: おそらくソースコードが`UTF-8`でコマンドプロンプトからコンパイルする際に`SJIS`で読まれているせいかと思います。`javac -encoding UTF-8 wrqrqr.java`ではいかがでしょうか？

Comment: できました。。　ありがとうございます。。

Answer (score 2):

原因は`wrqrqr`クラスに`public static void main(String[] args)`が定義されていない為です。
ソースコードを下記の様に修正して、コンパイル後に実行すれば、画面に`5`と表示されると思います。

**ソースコード:**

```
public class wrqrqr {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO 自動生成されたメソッド・スタブ
        int x;
        x=5;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

**コマンド:**

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 wrqrqr.java
java wrqrqr
5
```

**余談:**

ソースコードがBOM(byte order mark)付きのUTF-8の場合、コンパイル時にエラーが出るかと思います。
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28043356/4366193

ツールやエディタ等でBOMを削除してください。
PowerShellの場合、下記のコマンドでBOMを削除できます。

```
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText((Get-Location).Path + '\wrqrqr.java', (Get-Content .\wrqrqr.java -Encoding UTF8 -Raw))
```

Answer (score 1):

`javafx.application.application`は関係ないですね。
`public static class helloworld{`と対応する閉じカッコを消せばOKです。

Comment: public static class helloworld{と閉じカッコをひとつ消してみましたが変わりませんでした。。

Answer (score 1):

```
java wrqrqr$helloworld
```

or

```
java wrqrqr\$helloworld
```