# javaプログラムで実行エラーの解決方法を教えてください。

Tags: java

エラー: メイン・メソッドがクラスEx22で見つかりません。次のようにメイン・メソッドを定義してください。
   public static void main(String[] args)
またはJavaFXアプリケーション・クラスはjavafx.application.Applicationを拡張する必要があります
と出るのですが、コンパイルはできているのに、実行の時になぜエラーを出しているのかわかりません。
プログラムは以下になっています。

```
public class Ex22 {

  public static void main(){

    int[] moneyList = {121902,8302,55100};

    for (int i = 0; i < moneyList.length; i++){

      System.out.println(moneyList[i]);

    }

    for(int m : moneyList){

      System.out.println(m);

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: 同じかもしれません　https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6461/

Answer (score 1):

mainメソッドの引数として、String[] args を入れる必要があります。

Comment: 補足すると、javaコマンドは、指定されたクラスのstatic void main(String[])という定義を持ったメソッドを探してそれを実行しようとします。static void main()（引数が空）の関数が定義されていてもそれは実行対象ではないのでjavaコマンドから見たら無意味なのです。String[]型の引数を追加すれば動きます。

Answer (score 1):

プロジェクトがJavaFXアプリケーションであれば警告の通りApplicationクラスを拡張する必要があります。
プロジェクトが普通のJavaプロジェクトとかであれば"tokoi"さんの回答通りmainメソッドの引数を指定する必要があります。

使用しているIDEやどうやって実行しようとしているのか、また何をしたいのかを明記すればもっと具体的な回答が得られると思いますよ。